# Correlation calculation in R

Tags: r, correlation

Hope you can assist me.
I need to calculate the Correlation between budget and total.gross in the table imdb.movies.nomissingbud and although I wrote according to what I found on the Internet, it gives me an error.
In addition, how do I calculate the correlation between budget and total.gross in the table imdb.movies.nomissingbud **without movies that have the word "war" in the genre**?

Thank you!

```
setwd("C:/Users/hart/Desktop/R")

imdb.movies <- read.csv("IMDB_movies.csv")
head(imdb.movies)

imdb.movies$budget <- as.numeric(as.character(imdb.movies$budget))

## create new variable

imdb.movies.nomissingbud <- 
  imdb.movies[is.na(imdb.movies$budget) == FALSE, ]

print(cor(imdb.movies.nomissingbud$budget, imdb.movies.nomissingbud$total.gross, method = "pearson"))
```

[image]

```
dput(head(imdb.movies))

structure(list(id = c("10itemsorless.htm", "10thandwolf.htm", 
"11thhour.htm", "12.htm", "1208eastofbucharest.htm", "127hours.htm"
), title = c("10 Items or Less ", "10th &amp; Wolf ", "The 11th Hour ", 
"12", "12:08 East of Bucharest ", "127 Hours "), total.gross = c(83291L, 
54702L, 707343L, 125120L, 91881L, 18335230L), distributer = c("ThinkFilm", 
"ThinkFilm", "Warner Independent", "Sony Classics", "Tartan", 
"Fox Searchlight"), genre = c("Comedy", "Crime Drama", "Documentary", 
"Foreign", "Foreign", "Drama"), release.date = c("1/12/2006", 
"18/08/2006", "17/08/2007", "4/3/2009", "6/6/2007", "5/11/2010"
), runtime = c("1 hrs. 22 min.", "1 hrs. 50 min.", "1 hrs. 33 min.", 
"2 hrs. 39 min.", "1 hrs. 29 min.", "1 hrs. 33 min."), budget = c(NA, 
8e+06, NA, NA, NA, 1.8e+07), MPAA.rating = c("R", "R", "PG", 
"PG-13", "Unrated", "R")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


summary(imdb.movies.nomissingbud$budget)
```

Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.
1  15000000  30000000  48322574  65000000 300000000

```
summary(imdb.movies.nomissingbud$total.gross)
```

Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.      NA's
9812  11475181  35607310  59989432  80079357 533345358         4

Comment: Can you post `dput(head(imdb.movies))`

Comment: Also `summary(imdb.movies.nomissingbud$budget)` and `summary(imdb.movies.nomissingbud$total.gross)` might be useful.

Comment: (1) I see no errors. (2) Not sure why it's considered a good thing, why is `cond == FALSE` better than the canonical `!cond`? (3) You try to remove `NA` values from `budget` but I see no effort to do the same for `total.gross`. Have you checked that? (4) Have you checked that your `nomissingbudget` frame actually has rows? For example, `cor(0[0], 1[0])` (two empty numeric vectors) returns `NA` despite the lack of `NA` values.

Comment: Only the NAs from budget are removed. If there is a single NA in total.gross, NA will be returned. Something like `imdb.movies.nomissing <- imdb.movies[complete.cases(imdb.movies[, c("budget", "total.gross")])]` followed by `with(imdb.movies.nomissing, cor(budget, total.gross))` should work.

Comment: Thank you very much but still no answer helped me.
In the meantime, I added things you asked me to post